# Drupal 8 Behind Kong

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I have a Drupal 8 site.
I am using Kong as a reverse proxy for it to enable me to run other things on my server.

My site is configured as https but Kong forwards it to the server without https.

Most of the site works but any place where a button needs to be pressed goes wrong. For some reason the browser is thrown to a non-ssl url.

I think most of the urls must be relative but there must be some point where it is set becasue the button submissions push the browser to a non-ssl endpoint. I have checked settings.php but I can't find one.

Does anyone know of a setting that might help?

## Update 1

I have looked at the chrome logs and ticked 'preserve log' I have discovered I am getting a 302 from the server:

Request URL: https://code.metcarob.com/user/logout
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 302 Found
Remote Address: 78.31.105.225:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

I have checked my nginx config and I don't give any 302's out. (I do give out 301's for other reasons but they are not hitting here.)
Why would Drupal give out 302 to broswers, and when it does why isn't it respecting https?

## Update 2

The login button is using a method 303.

Request URL: https://code.metcarob.com/user/login
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 303 See Other
Remote Address: 78.31.105.225:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Comment: What Ineed to know is what is the difference between the button press submission vs clicking a link.

Comment: Why would one work but not the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was forced to use a terrible hack to get round this.

In my Drupal 8 settings file I has to add:

> $settings['reverse_proxy'] = TRUE;
>   $settings['reverse_proxy_addresses'] = array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

Setting the reverse_proxy_addresses to REMOTE_ADDR allows spoofing but because my Kong server and Drupal servers are both in the same encrypted docker swarm network I don't think this is a problem.

This led me to one remaining problem. Kong runs on port 8443. It is not possible to change it but the docker container can have port 443 exposed. The problem is this then ends up sending the X_FORWARDED_PORT header with the value 8443. Every time a form in Drupal submits the browser is directed to 8443. I found I could override this by doing the following:

$settings['reverse_proxy_port_header'] = 'X_SOMERANDOMHEADERIDONTUSE';

This makes drupal ignore the header and redirects work.